# Как уместить сразу несколько строк в jQuery .append ?

Tags: jquery, javascript, append

Иногда требуется добавить к элементу сложную конструкцию или сгенерированную таблицу.

Писать так не всегда удобно:

```
$('#div_table').append('<table>');
$('#div_table').append('<tr>');
$('#div_table').append('<td>');
$('#div_table').append('12');
$('#div_table').append('</td>');
$('#div_table').append('<td>');
$('#div_table').append('13');
$('#div_table').append('</td>');
$('#div_table').append('</tr>');
$('#div_table').append('</table>');
```

Если писать внутри одного append в строку, то становится нечитабельно. 
Записать в таком виде JS вроде не позволяет:

```
$('#div_table').append('<table>
                           <tr>
                               <td>12</td>
                               <td>13</td>
                           </tr>
                         </table>');
```

Подскажите кто как с этим делом справляется? Пишу в SublimeText2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#div_table').append('<table>'+
'<tr>'+
'<td>12</td>'+
'<td>13</td>'+
'</tr>'+
'</table>');

$('#div_table').append('<table>\
                           <tr>\
                               <td>12</td>\
                               <td>13</td>\
                           </tr>\
                         </table>');
```

А вот так:

```
$('#div_table').append('<table>');
$('#div_table').append('<tr>');
$('#div_table').append('<td>');
$('#div_table').append('12');
$('#div_table').append('</td>');
$('#div_table').append('<td>');
$('#div_table').append('13');
$('#div_table').append('</td>');
$('#div_table').append('</tr>');
$('#div_table').append('</table>');
```

Никогда так не пишите :-) Представьте, что вам нужно через портал груз переправить. Что лучше: один раз открыть и переправить сразу весь груз, или открывать по 25 раз и провозить груз по частям? А открытие-то портала кушает немало энергии :-)

Comment: Спасибо, буду учить синтаксис)

Comment: @Лисёнок поставьте палцу вверх! Хочу кое с кем поквитаться.

Answer (score 0):

Предложу свой вариант, так как делаю обычно я. http://jsfiddle.net/GSKn8/ Возможно, по производительности такой вариант уступает чистому HTML. Но используя такой подход можно легко навешивать события на созданные элементы и в более красивом виде задавать HTML аттрибуты. Плюс такой код легче поддерживать